# How to animate a div to move from end to end infinitely

Tags: html, css

Html

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
#box{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

I want the div "box" to move from left end of the browser to right end & to continue the same as a loop.
How can i do that with CSS alone ?

Comment: Should it go back and forth or just restart?

Comment: It should disappear at the right end & should appear at the left again. @Chrillewoodz

Comment: This may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/gk8s1mwr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it nicely:

```
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: left-to-right 5s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes left-to-right {
  from {left: 0;}
  to {left: 100%;}
}

@keyframes left-to-right {
  from {left: 0;}
  to {left: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: This works , but can you update the answer so that the part of the box that moved after the right end will appear at the left end simultaneously ? @Chrillewoodz

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? You want the hidden part of the div at the right end to be visible to to the left? Not sure I can accomplish that using only CSS since a div can't be at the left and to the right at the same time.

Comment: No problem :) Thanks anyway @Chrillewoodz